# Does the leading dimension in cuBLAS allow for accessing any submatrix?

Tags: cuda, blas, cublas

I'm trying to understand the idea of the leading dimension in cuBLAS. It's mentioned that `lda` must always be greater than or equal to the # of rows in a matrix.

If I have a 100x100 matrix A and I wanted to access A(90:99, 0:99), what would be the arguments of `cublasSetMatrix`? `lda` specifies the number of rows between the elements in the same column(100 in this case), but where would I specify the 90? I can only see a way by adjusting `*A`.

The function definition is:

```
cublasStatus_t cublasSetMatrix(int rows, int cols, int elemSize, const void *A, int lda, void *B, int ldb)
```

And I'm also guessing that I wouldn't be able to transfer the bottom right 3x3 portion of a 5x5 matrix given the length limits.

Comment: The answer would dependent on the storage order of the matrix. Which way is A stored?

Comment: @talonmies Column-major

Comment: Yes, you can access an arbitrary sub-matrix with CUBLAS (or any BLAS, for that matter). Please decode your notation. `A(90:99, 0:99)` = column 99 of rows 90 through 0? Why are the rows specified in reverse order?

Comment: I'm confused myself. I meant columns 90-99 each with 100 rows with indices 0-99.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to "adjust `*A`", as you called it. The pointer that is given to this function must be the starting entry of the respective sub-matrix.

You did not say whether your matrix `A` is actually the input- or the output matrix, but this should not change much, conceptually.

Assuming you have the following code:

```
// The matrix in host memory
int rowsA = 100;
int colsA = 100;
float *A = new float[rowsA*colsA];

// Fill A with values
...

// The sub-matrix that should be copied to the device.
// The minimum index is INCLUSIVE
// The maximum index is EXCLUSIVE
int minRowA = 0;
int maxRowA = 100;
int minColA = 90;
int maxColA = 100;
int rowsB = maxRowA-minRowA;
int colsB = maxColA-minColA;

// Allocate the device matrix
float *dB = nullptr;
cudaMalloc(&dB, rowsB * colsB * sizeof(float));
```

Then, for the `cublasSetMatrix` call, you have to compute the starting element of the source matrix:

```
float *sourceA = A + (minRowA + minColA * rowsA);
cublasSetMatrix(rowsB, colsB, sizeof(float), sourceA, rowsA, dB, rowsB);
```

And this is where the `90` that you asked for comes into play: It is the `minColA` in the computation of the source pointer.